# Usage of "of" prepositions sequence

Tags: word-order, prepositions

Today, I have encountered the following sentence in a documentation:

> Department of development and support of information systems of ABC JSC

I have argued about the correctness of using this "of"s sequence - for me, it sounded both too complex and "too Russian". However, I couldn't explain why.

Which of the following sentences are correct, and why?

- Department of Development and Support of Information Systems of ABC JSC
- Department of Information Systems Development and Support of ABC JSC
- Information Systems Development and Support Department of ABC JSC
- Information Systems' Development and Support Department of ABC JSC

For me, the third one sounds the best, but how can I argue it?
If both variants are OK, then how to decide which one to use?
Does this problem actually occur among native speakers?

Another one example:

- Head of Sales Department
- Sales Department Head
- Sales Department's head

Which are correct, and which are commonly used?

I have even stumbled upon this problem when I was writing this question.
Wouldn't **"Of" prepositions sequence usage** title be better?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it think it should be *"development of and support for"*. But using just one preposition is okay, and *of* is better than *for*.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

To my knowledge, there is no rule about the sequence of "ofs".  It depends on the name of the organization.

=> I am a member of the Latter Day Saints of the Church of Christ (or whatever).
=>  The Department of Defense of the United States of America.
=>  The Ministry of Finance of France.

For your second question:

1. the Head of the Sales Department (okay)
2. the Sales Department Head (okay) ("Sales Department" = noun phrase acting as an adj.)
3. the Sales Department's head (Incorrect. Possessive relates to ownership.  The Sales Department doesn't OWN him.  That would be slavery.)